# Unvisible application content within VNC / XFCE

Tags: x11, xfce, vnc, matlab, tigervnc

I do have a weird render issue of some applications that I'm running within a **tigervnc** session on a remote host where **XFCE** is started.

As you can see from the screenshot, while applications display correctly their content (e.g. file browser, visual studio code, ..), the matlab window does not show its content. I believe this is **not a matlab related issue** since If I run matlab through a "ssh -X" session on the same host, it is displayed properly.

It might be related, I have also seen that kind of rendering issue with matplotlib when triggering the pyplot.show(), the image is kind of transparent and we see the image to display mixed with the desktop background image.

[image]

If necessary, the xstartup script is

```
#!/bin/sh
# Start Xfce4 Desktop
[ -x /etc/vnc/xstartup ] && exec /etc/vnc/xstartup
[ -r $HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
vncconfig -iconic &
dbus-launch --exit-with-session xfce4-session &
```

and the vncserver is ran with `vncserver -SecurityTypes None -depth 32 -geometry 1680x1050 -cleanstale`

Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VNC servers usually just use the screengrab functionality of X11 to get the current picture shown on the screen, then compress that, and send it to you.

That doesn't work if X11 doesn't know the screen content, which is the norm for programs using OpenGL accelerated on hardware. Your Matlab is doing exactly that. If you run it via `ssh -X`, hardware acceleration is disabled, and you get pixels (but much slower).

I would also not even be sure that Matlab doesn't have a detection for that mode, just to annoy people who buy one matlab license and run it on a VNC server for a whole company.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Following your comment, I did a step forward and I'm now able to see the content of the matlab application by running x11vnc rather than tigervnc. It is yet a bit more cumbersome as it requires to run `Xvfb`, `xfce4-session` and then `x11vnc` as indicated here: http://labo.lcprod.net/2016/02/un-gestionnaire-de-fenetre-xfce-par-le-biais-de-vnc-x11vnc-sur-un-serveur-x-virtuel-xvfb/ .